# Simulating class properties in (Win32) Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, static-methods

In [Simulating class properties in (Win32) Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa031505a.htm), there's this trick for defining 'class *properties*' as well as class methods:

```
unit myObjectUnit;

interface

type
  TMyObject = Class
  private
    class function GetClassInt: integer;
    class procedure SetClassInt(const Value: integer);
  public
    property ClassInt : integer read GetClassInt 
                                write SetClassInt;
  end;

implementation

{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
const TMyObject_ClassInt : integer = 0;
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}

class function TMyObject.GetClassInt: integer;
begin
  result := TMyObject_ClassInt;
end;

class procedure TMyObject.SetClassInt(
  const Value: integer);
begin
  TMyObject_ClassInt := value;
end;

end.
```

I will only have one such object in my code, so the warning that the GetClassInt and SetClassInt are always operating on the same typed constant *TMyObject_ClassInt* does not apply:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myObject : TMyObject;
begin
  myObject.ClassInt := 2005;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myObject : TMyObject;
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(myObject.ClassInt));
end;
```

(This illustrates that warning: Click 1 then 2 and the message shows 2005, not 0).

Still, this code smells a bit fishy. **Can I expect problems** (other than the warning above)? **Is there a better way?**.

BTW I'm not talking about the brute force $WRITEABLECONST OFF - instead of returning to the previous state. That can be circumvented by:

```
{$IFOPT J-}
{$DEFINE WC_WAS_OFF}
{$ENDIF}
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
const TMyObject_ClassInt : integer = 0;
{$IFDEF WC_WAS_OFF}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Why not just declare `var TMyObject_ClassInt : integer = 0;` and don't care about `WRITEABLECONST`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things that need to be specified here:

First of all, since you've tagged this as XE2, it supports [Class Properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Properties#Class_Properties) properly, with [Class Field Variables](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Fields).  This has been the case since (I think) Delphi 2009.

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    strict private
      class var         // Note fields must be declared as class fields
        FRed: Integer;
        FGreen: Integer;
        FBlue: Integer;
      public             // ends the class var block
        class property Red: Integer read FRed write FRed;
        class property Green: Integer read FGreen write FGreen;
        class property Blue: Integer read FBlue write FBlue;
  end;
```

Which can be accesed as:

```
TMyClass.Red := 0;
TMyClass.Blue := 0;
TMyClass.Green := 0;
```

For older versions of Delphi, this workaround is valid, though I'd use a unit variable instead of a writable constant as Uli suggested.  In all cases, your primary problem is multithreaded access.

Answer (score 1):

Class fields are supported for some time now (I think since Delphi 2009 at least), you declare them like

```
type
  TMyObject = Class
  public
    class var ClassInt : integer;
  end;
```

See the [Class Fields](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Fields) topic in the help.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration is valid since Delphi-2009:

```
type
  TMyObject = Class
  strict private
    class var
       MyClassInt : integer;
  private
    class function GetClassInt: integer; static;
    class procedure SetClassInt(const Value: integer); static;
  public
    class property ClassInt : integer read GetClassInt
                                write SetClassInt;
  end;
```

Make your class methods static and declare your property as [`class property`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Methods#Class_Static_Methods).